# Randomise stream links in jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have a modded jPlayer that connects to a shoutcast/icecast source.

I want to make jPlayer randomly connect between 2 or more url's upon opening the page.

For example if i have 2 links:

1. www.example.com:8000/live
2. www.example.com:8000/live2

Then i need jPlayer to randomly choose one of them when opening the page.
The purpose is to prevent over-load on one server.

How should i go about it in the jQuery code?

*jQuery:*

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://www.example.com:8000/live"
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js/",
        wmode: "window",
        solution: "flash,html",
        supplied: "mp3",
        preload: "none",
        volume:0.75,
        cssSelectorAncestor: "",
        cssSelector: {
                play: "#play",
                pause: "#pause"
        }
    });

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.pause, function(event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("clearMedia");
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: "http://www.example.com:8000/live"
        });
    });
```

Comment: why not let the server decide instead? one url that redirects with basic load balancing logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question you can do the following.

```
var servers = ["www.example.com:8000/live", "www.example.com:8000/live2"];
var server = servers[Math.floor(Math.random() * servers.length)];
```

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
  mp3: server
});
```

---

Notwithstanding this is not an optimal way to address your real problem:

> The purpose is to prevent over-load on one server.

You should consider using [**load balancing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29).

Comment: I get unexpected identifier and dont see the problem..  var servers = ["http://**.**.**:443/;stream/1", "http://**.**.**.**:8000/live"];
 var server = servers[Math.floor(Math.random() * servers.length)];
  ready: function(event) {
   $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: server
   }).jPlayer("play");

Comment: @TonalDev, that code **can't** go there. For example, place it at the beginning of your code

Comment: Yup just noticed i put it outside the function..if i put it inside it will randomise..thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get one of X random urls in either your server-side language or in javascript. Then simply pass the randomized value to `mp3:`

```
var randomUrl = getRandomUrl();
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind(...) {
       mp3: randomUrl;
}
```